On computing $\int_0^\infty \frac{x\cos(ax)}{(1+x^2)(1+2\sqrt{1+x^2})^2}\,\mathrm dx$
Few days ago I revisited this post I saved and was trying to come up with something to solve analytically this integral:
$$I(a)\equiv\int_0^\infty \dfrac{x\cos(ax)}{(1+x^2)(1+2\sqrt{1+x^2})^2}\,\mathrm dx$$
I'd appreciate some help on solving it even if by contour integration it is not possible.

That said, the following are some remarks on this integral I found during these past days:

The integral is odd and thus we cannot apply $\dfrac{1}{2}\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty$.

It can also be represented as (still odd though...)
$$I(a)=\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm da}\int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin(ax)}{(1+x^2)(1+2\sqrt{1+x^2})^2}\,\mathrm dx$$

Using IBP we can reduce the exponent of the $1+2\sqrt{1+x^2}$ term:
$$I(a)=\dfrac{1}{6}-\dfrac{a}{2}\int_0^\infty\dfrac{\sin(ax)}{\sqrt{1+x^2}(1+2\sqrt{1+x^2})}\,\mathrm dx-\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\dfrac{x\cos(ax)}{(1+x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}(1+2\sqrt{1+x^2})}\,\mathrm dx$$

I managed to convert it into an ODE in $a$,
$$I''(a)-I(a)=-\int_0^\infty\dfrac{x\cos(ax)}{(1+2\sqrt{1+x^2})^2}\,\mathrm dx\equiv f(a),$$
but once I solved it using Laplace Transform + Convolution it turns out the solution diverges due to $f(a)$ most likely.

Its branch points are $i$ and $-i$ and the most useful branch cuts may be the one joining both branch points or the one going to $\pm\infty$ along the imaginary axis. That so, the most useful contours might be quarter circle, semi circle or rectangle, all the while avoiding the branch cuts. You might be able to relate integrals on the real axis to the one on the imaginary axis parametrized by $z: iy,\ y\in(\infty,0]$ using the quarter circle contour. Another idea would be to use multiple contours and try to obtain simpler integrals.


I haven't tried series expansion but I doubt it's easier either...

$\mathbf{EDIT\ 1}:$ This might or might not be useful too:
$$\dfrac{1}{1+2\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\int_0^1 t^{2\sqrt{1+x^2}}\, \mathrm dt$$

$\mathbf{EDIT\ 2\ on\ the\ ODE\ solution}:$ We know $I(0)=\log\left(\dfrac{3}{2}\right)-\dfrac{1}{3}$ and $I'(0)=0$, therefore, applying the LT to the ODE we obtain
$$s^2 I(s)-sI(0)-I(s)=\mathcal L\{f(a)\}\implies I(s)=\dfrac{sI(0)}{s^2-1}+\underbrace{\dfrac{1}{s^2-1}}_{\mathcal L\{\sinh(a)\}}\cdot \mathcal L\{f(a)\}$$
If we apply the inverse we get to this result:
$$I(a)=I(0)\cosh(a)-\int_0^a\int_0^\infty\dfrac{x\cos(tx)\sinh(a-t)}{(1+2\sqrt{1+x^2})^2}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dt$$
But the double integral diverges I think.

The integral in your ODE is also equivalent to$$\frac\partial{\partial a}\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(ax)}{\left(1+2\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)^2},dx$$which may be easier to evaluate (if at all possible), although solving for $I(a)$ might be opening a can of worms.

This can be expressed as
$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial a}\int_{[0,1]^2}\int_0 ^\infty e^{2\sqrt{1+x^2}\log(zy)}\sin(ax),\mathrm dx,\mathrm dy,\mathrm dz$$
Is there by any chance a special function involving this type of integral?

let $u = 1 + x^2$
then:
$$
2I(a) = \int_1^\infty \frac{\cos(a\sqrt{u-1})}{4u^2 + 4u\sqrt{u} + u} du
$$
knowing the integral converges(why ?) we can write the following:
$$
\cos x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{(2n)!} \Rightarrow \cos (a\sqrt{u-1}) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n a^{2n}(u-1)^n}{(2n)!}
\Rightarrow
2I(a) = \int_1^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n a^{2n}}{(2n)!}\frac{(u-1)^n}{4u^2 + 4u\sqrt{u} + u} du = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n a^{2n}}{(2n)!} \int_1^\infty \frac{(u-1)^n}{4u^2 + 4u\sqrt{u} + u} du
$$
notice that :
$$
J(n) = \int_1^\infty \frac{(u-1)^n}{4u^2 + 4u\sqrt{u} + u} du = \int_1^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{{n \choose k}(-1)^{n-k}u^k}{4u^2 + 4u\sqrt{u} + u} du = 
\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}(-1)^{n-k}\int_1^\infty \frac{u^{k-1}}{4u + 4\sqrt{u} + 1}du
$$
$$
K(n) = \frac{1}{2}\int_1^\infty \frac{t^n}{(t+\frac{1}{2})^2}dt = (-1)^{n-1}(\frac{1}{2})^n
nB(-\frac{1}{2};1-n, 0)+\frac{1}{3} $$
$$
J(n) = \sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}(-1)^{n-k}(\frac{1}{2})^{2k-3}
(2k-3)B(-\frac{1}{2};4-2k, 0)
$$
$$
16I(a) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a^{2n}}{(2n)!}\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}(-1)^{k}(\frac{1}{2})^{2k}
(2k-3)B(-\frac{1}{2};4-2k, 0)
$$
